# Memory leaks when using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Will such code cause a memory leak?

```
unsigned char *ptr = new unsigned char[2];
ptr++; //pointer now points to the second member of array
delete [] ptr;
```

Comment: I doubt it is even a defined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the standard (e.g. [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation#3) online draft version), the behaviour of `delete`-ing a pointer, which has not been obtained previously by `new`, is undefined:

> **3.7.4.2 Deallocation functions**
>
> (3) If a deallocation function terminates by throwing an exception, the
>   behavior is undefined. The value of the first argument supplied to a
>   deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the
>   deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library, the
>   call has no effect. **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined if the value
>   supplied to operator delete(void*) in the standard library is not one
>   of the values returned by a previous invocation of either operator
>   new(std::size_t) or operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)
>   in the standard library, and the behavior is undefined if the value
>   supplied to operator delete in the standard library is not
>   one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either operator
>   new or operator new[](std::size_t, const
>   std::nothrow_t&) in the standard library.**

The value of `ptr+1` is not the one returned by `new[]`, and hence the call to `delete[] (ptr+1)` is UB. Anything can happen, including that it seems to work correctly; But it is for sure *not guaranteed to work correctly*.

Comment: thanks a lot. Does that means that i have to avoid pointer arithmetic on pointers obtained by new?

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behavior as mentioned [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete)

> delete [] expression
>
> expression must be a null pointer value or a pointer value previously
>   obtained by an array form of new-expression. If expression is anything
>   else, including if it's a pointer obtained by the non-array form of
>   new-expression, the behavior is undefined.

This makes sense as `delete[]` would expect to get some information about number of elements to be deleted from the pointer supplied, which it would not found if a different pointer is passed.